# How do I retrieve the actual string selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Given a select tag with options:

```
<div id='mydiv'>0</div>
    <select id="mysel">
        <option id="opt1">a</option>
        <option id="opt2">b</option>
    </select>...
```

How do I retrieve the actual string selection?  Ie.  How do I retrieve the actual "select#mysel" from the var mysel?

example of how this might be used?

```
var mysel = $("select#mysel");
var myopt = $(mysel.actualstringselection + " option");
var myoptcount = myopt.length;
alert("my option count:" + myoptcount );
$("#mydiv").html(myoptcount);
```

Comment: Can you please add more details about the problem you're trying to solve? As it is, this question is essentially nonsensical.

Comment: *"If I have a variable set to a specific css selector"* Nowhere in your code do you have a variable containing a CSS selector. That would look something like this: `var variable = "#mysel";` The first line of your code has a variable that (after the line runs) contains a reference to a jQuery object that contains zero or more DOM elements jQuery found when you passed a selector into `$()`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I should also point out that the selector `mysel myopt` will attempt to select any `<myopt>` elements that are the child of a `<mysel>` element. @T.J.Crowder's answer below explains how to use your `mysel` variable to find child elements.

Comment: I'm looking for a possible solution to my problem which is to use an existing selector assigned to a variable and perform further selections on it.

Comment: I fixed code to show option instead of myopt.

Comment: TJ I was really interested for something like this though I know it doesn't exist: $(mysel.selector + " option")...

Comment: I think he is asking for the text value of the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer for updated question**:

> How do I retrieve the actual "select#mysel" from the var mysel?
>
> example of how this might be used?
>
> ```
> var mysel = $("select#mysel");
> var myopt = $(mysel.actualstringselection + " option");
> ```

So basically, you want the original selector string that you passed into `$()` in order to get `mysel`.

You can't get that. jQuery never offered an official way to do it. For a long time, there was an undocumented property on jQuery instances that contained it (mostly, most of the time), but it was always undocumented because it wasn't entirely reliable, and it doesn't even exist in current versions.

So instead, you can do it yourself:

```
 var selector = "select#mysel";
 var mysel = $(selector).data("selector", selector);
 // Presumably somewhere else where you no longer have the `selector` variable:
 var myopt = $(mysel.data("selector") + " option");
```

**But**, you wouldn't want to use that for the above. (You'd use `find`, as described originally [below]). The only reason I can think of for such a thing is if you've changed the DOM and want to repeat the original query. E.g.:

```
mysel = $(mysel.data("selector")); // Goes looking for the elements again
```

---

**Original answer**:

If after this line:

```
var mysel = $("select#mysel");
```

...you're trying to use `mysel` to find something within the descendant elements of any DOM elements in that jQuery object, you use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
var optionElements = mysel.find("option");
```

Comment: I am trying to use the first selection to further my second selection but use variables instead of the actual jquery selectors to do this.

Comment: When you say "use variables instead of...jQuery selectors," which selectors do you want to swap out with which variables?

Comment: I removed this as answer b/c I had to change the question in the hopes that it might get reopened.

Comment: @RetroCoder: I've answered the updated question as well, but this is looking *seriously* fishy. What's your **real world** use case for knowing what the original selector was? Clearly it's not to find the option elements, as my original answer told you how to do that...

Comment: I was trying to remove certain options like Not Applicable or Select which were at the top of the list of options or at the bottom of the list of options.  But was curious on how I could simply tack on just the [value='NA'] or [value=''] and remove those options if a country had or did not have states.  Like US and CA might have states but like most other countries don't have states.

Comment: @RetroCoder: Again the original answer has the answer: `mysel.find("option[value=NA]").remove();` Don't think about storing selector strings. Think about objects.

Comment: Yes I agree, but if your curious about another way then you ask the question even if its against the grain right?